# Multiplying a complex<double> and complex<float>

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading

I'm using the `std::polar()` function which returns `complex<double>` but I want to multiply it by `complex<float>`, I tried doing operator overload but I'm not sure how to do it, if there is an alternative to std::polar which returns `complex<float>` that would be even better.

Here's my full code:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <complex>
#include <valarray>

typedef std::complex<float> Complex;
typedef std::valarray<Complex> CArray;

void fft(CArray& x)
{
    const size_t N = x.size();
    if (N <= 1) return;

    CArray even = x[std::slice(0, N / 2, 2)]; //split the inputs in even / odd indices subarrays
    CArray  odd = x[std::slice(1, N / 2, 2)];

    // conquer
    fft(even); 
    fft(odd);

    // combine
    for (size_t k = 0; k < N / 2; ++k)
    {
        Complex t = std::polar(1.0, -2 * M_PI * k / N) * odd[k];
        x[k] = even[k] + t;
        x[k + N / 2] = even[k] - t;
    }
}

Complex operator*(std::complex<double>, std::complex<float>)
{
    return std::complex<double> * std::complex<float>;
}
```

Comment: `std::polar`'s return type is based on the type passed in see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/polar If you pass in `float`s you get a `std::complex<float>` out.  As the code passes in `double`s it gets a `std::complex<double>` out.

Comment: you just need to give names to your parameters and multiply those rather than the types?

Comment: Might help: complex(z) = complex(x) * complex(y) = (real(x) * real(y) - img(x) * img(y), real(x) * img(y) + img(x) * real(y))

Comment: As you still need to convert float to double I'd just create a `complex<double>` from the `complex<float>` and do the multiplication in the larger type. If need be, you still can convert back.

Comment: can you show me how would that look? @Aconcagua

Comment: `std::complex<double> x, y; std::complex<double> z(x.real() * y.real() - x.imag() * y.imag(), x.real() * y.imag() + x.imag() * y.real());` – any of them can be `float`, if need be, implicit conversions are performed.

Comment: A quick fix: `Complex t = std::polar<float>(1.0, -2 * M_PI * k / N) * odd[k];` Note explicit template parameter passed to `std::polar`. This way, it returns `std::complex<float>`. Another way is to write `Complex(std::polar(1.0, -2 * M_PI * k / N))`, explicitly casting the result to `std::complex<float>`

Comment: so many great answers thank you!

Comment: For completeness: second variant: `std::complex<float> x; std::complex<double>y; std::complex<double>z = std::complex<double>(x) * y;`

Comment: I personally wouldn't care for `float` at all and do everything in double. Modern hardware calculates in 80 bits in any case, so no benefits with float anyway and you are just giving away precision for no value. Sole excpeption: If you have large masses of values, then floats can require significantly less memory.

Comment: Yea I do have large masses of values my mentor told me switch to float saying it would be significantly faster because I'm working with vectors and in the future I'll work with the GPU